# _tkinter.TclError: image "\full\directory\link.gif" doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm sorry to be a pain, and I know that there are god knows how many other questions referring to this 'image doesn't exist' tkinter error, however, none of the ones that I have found appear to have an issue with the entire directory, they all seem to just be referring to the file name only.

So, I'm trying to make a Logo Quiz, (I have removed some irrelevant code from the example because otherwise it will be too long to place here..)

However, when I try to show the logo, it tells me that the image doesn't exist.
Showing me an issue with the entire directory link, of which if I copy directly from the error and place into Windows Explorer, opens the image perfectly fine.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class Window(Frame):

    global questionstart
    def questionstart():
        if gameplayvar == 0:
            chosenlinknumber = random.randint(0, len(templist)-1)
            chosen = templist[chosenlinknumber]
            temp = chosen.split("\\")
            temp2 = temp[2].split(".")
            temp3 = temp2[0].split("L")

            global directory
            quizlogo_label = Label(root, image = directory)
            quizlogo_label.grid(row=1, column=2)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x590") 
root.iconbitmap(r'\\replacing\the\server\directory\Documents\pythontests\Logos\logoquizlogo_YVp_icon.ico')

C = Canvas(root, bg="blue", height=500, width=500)

possiblelinks = [
                '\\NewLogos\AdobeLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\AmazonLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\AppleLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\BMWLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\ChromeLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\DebianLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\DiscordLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\FirefoxLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\GoogleLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\MicrosoftLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\OperaLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\PhotoshopLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\PlayStationLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\PythonLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\TwitterLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\VisualStudioCodeLogo.gif',
                '\\NewLogos\WindowsLogo.gif'
            ]

templist = possiblelinks

chosenlinknumber = random.randint(0, len(templist)-1)
chosen = templist[chosenlinknumber]

p1 = '\\replacing\the\server\directory\Documents\pythontests'
directory = p1+chosen

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is what is returned when I run it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" "//replacing/the/server/directory/Documents/pythontests/tkinterimagetry1.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "//replacing/the/server/directory/Documents/pythontests/tkinterimagetry1.py", line 143, in quizstart
    questionstart()
  File "//replacing/the/server/directory/Documents/pythontests/tkinterimagetry1.py", line 121, in questionstart
    quizlogo_label = Label(root, image = directory)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "\\replacing\the\server\directory\Documents\pythontests\NewLogos\DiscordLogo.gif" doesn't exist
```

I don't have a clue what is causing it to not find the file as the directory that is being giving out as an error works perfectly fine in Windows Explorer..

Thanks,
Xan

Comment: I think the label needs an ImageTk instance, not the file path. and note you need to keep a reference to the opened ImageTk instance or it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I sadly don't quite understand how to fix that within my code.. I understand that it's getting garbage collected, I just can't figure out how to reference the ImageTk instance..

Answer (score 0):

this is the problematic part:

```
global directory
quizlogo_label = Label(root, image = directory)
```

the Label constructor expects the image to be passed in as an ImageTk Instance, not a string containing the filename.

it needs to be something like:

```
global directory
self.photo = Image.PhotoImage(directory)
self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)
quizlogo_label = Label(root, image = self.photo)
```

note that both instances of image classes as assigned as attributes of `self` which is the instance of `Window` so that they are not garbage collected when the function exits